# Pyhtin sockets: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, sockets, operating-system

I am trying to run a very basic Python socket exercise using UDP Protocol. I am getting this error on the server side:

File "udp_local_server.py", line 9, in  message, address = server_socket.recvfrom(65535)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Here is my server:

```
    import socket
    server_port = 21060
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', server_port))
    print (f"[SERVER] Listening at: {server_socket.getsockname()}")
    
    while True:
        message, address = server_socket.recvfrom(65535)
        modified_message = str(len(str(message).split(",")))
    
        print (f"[SERVER] The client at {address} originally sent {message}")
        
        server_socket.sendto(bytes(f"Server is sending back: {modified_message}", encoding='utf8'), address)
    
        server_socket.close()
```

Here is my client:

```
    import socket
    server_port = 21060
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    input_s = 'Hello, server!'
    client_socket.sendto(bytes(input_s, encoding='utf8'), ('127.0.0.1', server_port))
    input_s_modified, address = client_socket.recvfrom(65535)
    
    print (f"[CLIENT] Response from server is: {address, str(input_s_modified.decode('utf8'))}")
    
    client_socket.close()
```

What am I doing wrong? I know that similar errors are caused by Python closing from "the outside", but I just can't figure it out on my own.

Comment: There is a socket `close()` at the end of the server's loop, so the socket will exist only for one iteration. Looks like bad indentation of that line to me, BTW.

Comment: Yup. Thanks. Bad indentation strikes again.